# Access PHP Objects with namespace

Tags: php, object, namespaces

[image]

I am trying to integrate an API and its response is saved in $charge variable. I tried to access this via $charge->_status:protected but fail. How to access those variables?

Comment: The API likely offers a way to specifically access that protected string. A method such as `$charge->getStatus();` for instance.

Answer (score 2):

gIn your case it's just

```
$charge->getStatus();
```

The way you ask the question shows you've got a little misunderstanding. The property name is "`_status`" and it's [visibility](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php) is *protected*.

This is why the `print_r` output has it as "`_status:protected`" but that is not the property name, but an informative encoding.

*Protected* visibility means, that you can not access it via the class public interface. The module designer has added the public property method `getStatus()` (a so called "getter" method) so that it is accessible for reading.

You can find the method definition in the source-code here: https://github.com/CKOTech/checkout-php-library/blob/master/com/checkout/ApiServices/Charges/ResponseModels/Charge.php#L269

Answer (score 0):

Try as

```
$charge->_status
```

Based on the given image it seems that the _status is declared as protected and it won't allow you to access outside the class.

Comment: I understood that but API returns all of them are protected, not sure how to access them.

Comment: in case you have access to documentation, they might have function to get status. Pleas check on it.

Answer (score 0):

try this json response is in a variable named $charge, you must use json_decode and then do as like this example:

```
$decoded = json_decode($charge);
$result = $decoded->result;
$quote = $decoded->info->quote;
var_dump($result, $quote);
```

Comment: its not json new guy,

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$data = array(
    '_status:protected' => 'Authorized'
);
$arr = (object)$data;
// print_r($arr);
$key = '_status:protected';
echo $arr->$key;
?>
```

I think this will help you..